# Problema al agregar una restriccion unique a una tabla particionada

Tags: sql-server, indices, constraints

tengo una tabla particionada por la columna 'CODDOCUMENTO' Intento agregarle a la tabla un campo de tipo UNIQUEIDENTIFIER y con restricción UNIQUE, pero no me deja porque al parecer el index unique no es un index key o algo así. Este es mi código y abajo el error:

```
ALTER TABLE TB_DOCUMENTACION ADD [GUIDDOCUMENTO] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
            ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL UNIQUE DEFAULT (newid())
ALTER TABLE TB_DOCUMENTACION ADD ARCHIVO varbinary(max) FILESTREAM null
```

Error:

> Msg 1908, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Column 'CODDOCUMENTO' is partitioning column of the index 'UQ__TB_DOCUMENTA__66517D55'. Partition columns for a unique index must be a subset of the index key.
> Msg 1750, Level 16, State 0, Line 1
> Could not create constraint. See previous errors.

Answer (score 1):

SQL server exige que le entregues tu alma... o que al menos crees los índices UNIQUE como él puede manejarlos.

Para las tablas particionadas, MSSQL exige que los índices UNIQUE incluyan la columna usada en el particionamiento.

Así pues, tu nuevo índice debería crearse más o menos así:

```
ALTER TABLE TB_DOCUMENTACION 
ADD [GUIDDOCUMENTO] UNIQUEIDENTIFIER 
ROWGUIDCOL NOT NULL DEFAULT (newid());

-- Si no pones el GO entre las dos, MSSQL se queja porque lo que va después de acá no va a tener en cuenta lo que se haya ejecutado antes
GO

-- El atributo UNIQUE se lo damos en un INDEX creado explícitamente
CREATE
UNIQUE INDEX TB_DOCUMENTACION_UQ_GUIDOC
ON TB_DOCUMENTACION(CODDOCUMENTO,GUIDDOCUMENTO);

ALTER TABLE TB_DOCUMENTACION 
ADD ARCHIVO varbinary(max) FILESTREAM null
```

No recuerdo si esos atributos UNIQUEIDENTIFIER y ROWGUIDCOL puedan causar algún lío similar. De paso, te recomiendo que uses constraints explícitos para asignarle atributos not null, unique, PK, FK, etc., a tus columnas, pues eso te permite comparar más fácil versiones diferentes de la BD (si no los creas explícitos, la BD les pone nombres aleatorios y es más difícil comparar versiones de una tabla usando herramientas automatizadas).

---

**EDITO:** Algo muy importante sobre tu comentario. En efecto, el índice que se crea para el campo que se usa al particionar, se define como `CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX...`. Todos los demás índices DEBEN definirse como NONCLUSTERED (sólo se permite un índice CLUSTERED por tabla) con todo el resto de la sintaxis común y corriente. Así, el índice explícito UNIQUE podría también ir como:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX TB_DOCUMENTACION_UQ_GUIDOC
ON TB_DOCUMENTACION(GUIDDOCUMENTO);
```

Pasa además que te falla porque, por defecto, los UNIQUE constraints se crean CLUSTERED, así que él intenta usar lo que ya está, que es la columna particionada... todo muy MSSQL

Comment: MM creo q se me olvido comentar algo. Si dices que MSSQL exige que los indices unique incluyan la columna particionada. Pero esta columna de particion justo es la primary key el cual ps tiene su indice de tipo clustered. A lo mejor eso es lo que esta interfiriendo.

Comment: Edito para aclarar sobre tu comentario...